"Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN"
Whenever i try to import multiple excel through SSIS its giving me the same error mentioned below and also i tried to do the things like delayvalidation,etc.
[Excel Source [140]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
[Excel Source [140]] Error: Opening a rowset for "'Raw Data - Third Data Source'" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: One or more component failed validation.
I have already enabled the delay validation to true.
i have also changed the version to 32 bit.
i have checked the data has full access.
solution that can help me to resolve this issue struggling with this issue from last one month.

This error normally occurs when the file can't be validated, such as when it doesn't exist. I assume this is a deployed package? What have you deployed it to (you've tagged [ssms-2012], but that's just an IDE (like) application). How did you deploythe package? Via SSISDB? File System? Something else?
